# Python search by value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need a proper solution to search for a key in a nested data structures in Python.
Lets assume that I have variable with value 'check' and dict like this:

```
SERVICES = {
    'domain': ['check','whois','register'],
    'user': ['create','show','delete'],
    'invoice': ['toPdf','print']
}
```

What is the best way to check in which array-key is the 'check' value and return 'domain'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Standard approach:**

```
for k, v in SERVICES.items(): # or iteritems in Python 2
    if 'check' in v:
        print(k) # 'domain'
        break
```

If you expect to have multiple keys matching the condition, just remove `break`.

**Functional approach:**

```
>>> next(filter(lambda x: 'check' in SERVICES[x], SERVICES))
'domain'
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply iterate over the dictionary keys and check if `check` is one of the values of the value corresponding to the key. If you find it then give it to the `next` call.

```
print next(key for key in SERVICES if 'check' in SERVICES[key])
# domain
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SERVICES = {
    'domain': ['check','whois','register'],
    'user': ['create','show','delete'],
    'invoice': ['toPdf','print']
}

print [k for k in SERVICES if 'check' in SERVICES[k]]
```